# Retrieval of types from all assemblies in .net core solution in Rider/ReSharper

Tags: c#, .net-core, resharper, system.reflection, rider

We were using this code in a .NET core test project to get all of our relevant (in solution) assemblies, which we can use to get all their types:

```cs
List<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.GetName().FullName.StartsWith("Company.Name")).ToList();
```

This works <s>on Windows</s> via `dotnet test` or the visual studio test explorer, but <s>on Mac</s> on rider or the resharper test explorer it only returns the test assembly, which only includes the types specified in the test project.

It's been changed to recurse over `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`, which works as desired. I was wondering: **What is the difference between the <s>two platforms</s> test runners, and is there a simpler solution than `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The assemblies aren't loaded by design in order to match the regular dotnet assembly loading behaviour](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-483799)